# MySQL query, LAST_INSERT_ID(), works in phpmyadmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO service (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('test', '2001-01-01', 'test'); 
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO artikel_service (service_id) VALUES (@last_id);
```

The above query works great in `phpmyadmin` but not in PHP (XAMPP), why is that?

Comment: What you tried in PHP? Please show your code. Also mention if you are getting any error in PHP.

Comment: have you made a test database connection in php with error handling and showing all errors on

Answer (score -2):

You need to get last inserted id with this query separately: SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'service' and then in the result of above query you will get last inserted id (minus(-) 1) value in column 'Auto_increment'.

Comment: Sorry, it was by mistaken, it's corrected as "you will get last inserted id (minus(-) 1) value in column 'Auto_increment'."

Comment: as per my latest comments, I have used the same and worked perfectly at my side..

Comment: No, it does not work perfectly - it's **absolutely wrong**. Function to obtain last value generated by `auto_increment` is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. What you did is wrong. Why is it wrong? It doesn't take into account `auto_increment_offset`. You subtract by `1`. What if `auto_increment_offset` is not `1` but some other number? You get WRONG results.  Your "method" produces wrong results. Also, why would anyone use that over `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which exists for this purpose? Finally - why would this work in PHP (that we didn't see) and how does it fix the error (which we don't know what it is)?

Comment: If something works on your end, that doesn't mean you are correct or that you took every scenario into account. I've shown you the mistakes you made. You didn't explain why your solution fixes the problem. **You can't fix a problem if you don't know what it is**. OP didn't even include her code nor errors she's getting. Why would you blindly post some random piece of SQL that doesn't even do what you say it does?

Comment: First of all Relax buddy... I know what i am doing and what i replied.. you can carry on..

Comment: Since you know what you're doing, that must be the reason you got 2 downvotes. I'm relaxed "buddy". You should be grateful when you're taught correctly, not act like a little 12 year old angry kid. You can carry on now. Have a good day.

Comment: Ofcourse i am already to learn, however i believe that there is some way and manners to teach...anyway, apart from that you can refer your messages, who was getting angry.. good day buddy..

Comment: I don't know what you think you read, but I'm not angry, please read the text again. It's not my fault you perceive it as angry, it's purely objective and without feeling. It includes explanation and what you did wrong. There's 0 related to anything else.